# Adaptive payments 支払いエラーの理由について

Tags: paypal

PayPal Adaptive Payments chained paymentで第2受取人への支払を実施すると、下記エラーが発生してしまいます。

[errorId] 520002
[message] PA_Long_Error_Payment_Request_Invalidated

支払処理が出来なかった理由を取得することが可能ですか？
例えば口座の残高不足の為、など。

Answer (score 1):

IPNかPaymentDetails APIを使えばわかりますよ。